# System.ArgumentException: 'The service type ICommand is not supported. Parameter name: serviceType

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, httpconfiguration

i'm trying to use 
[Belgrade-SqlClient (Small async ADO.NET helper library)](http://jocapc.github.io/Belgrade-SqlClient/aspnet.html)

in c# web api
all is fine but when i try to register Icommand as a service

i got error:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'The service type ICommand is not supported. Parameter name: serviceType
```

this is my webapiconfig.cs where i add ICommand as service:

```
string Conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString; ;
        config.Services.Add(typeof(ICommand), new Command(Conn));
```

and this is Icommand:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Belgrade.SqlClient
{
    public interface ICommand : IQueryMapper, IQueryPipe
    {
        Task Exec();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you able to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your you are using **config.Services** as an IServiceCollection. Then you may need to use *AddTransient*, like this:

```
config.Services.AddTransient<ICommand>(() => new Command(Conn))
```

Comment: i used Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection to add Iservicecollection,but after i was try to services.AddMvc();  AddMvc does not exist. im trying to use wep api not aspnet.core waht can i do so :D